# Rails error in count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

The records counting is not displaying correctly in rails.

In controller i did

```
@notes_list = current_user.notes.where(known: false).order("title").group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
```

and in view i did

```
<%= @notes_list.count %>
```

But the entry is wrong. Can you find where the problem is?

Comment: What do you mean by entry is wrong?

Comment: What exactly you want to achive here?

Comment: The count is not correct when i write `<%= @notes_list.count %>` in the view

Comment: For example if the original entry in record is 20 its showing as 5

Comment: @Pavan Is there something i did wrong?

Comment: Do you want total number of notes for current user

Comment: You can check the SQL query generated in server logs and see it's what you want.

Comment: Yes. I number of notes for the current user with **known** column as false in DB